# Transparent (filter-like) gzip/gunzip in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying, just for fun, to connect a gzip Writer directly to a gzip Reader, so I could write to the Writer and read from the Reader on the fly. I expected to read exactly what I wrote.  I'm using gzip but I'd like to use this method also with crypto/aes, I suppose it should work very similar and it could be used with other reader/writers like jpeg, png...

This is my best option, that is not working, but I hope you can see what I mean: http://play.golang.org/p/7qdUi9wwG7

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []byte("Hello world!")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)

    var b bytes.Buffer

    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
    ungz, err := gzip.NewReader(&b)
    fmt.Println("err: ", err)

    gz.Write(s)
    gz.Flush()
    uncomp := make([]byte, 100)
    n, err2 := ungz.Read(uncomp)
    fmt.Println("err2: ", err2)
    fmt.Println("n: ", n)
    uncomp = uncomp[:n]
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", uncomp)
}
```

It seems that `gzip.NewReader(&b)` is trying to read immediately and a EOF is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do two things to make it work

1. Use an [io.Pipe](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) to connect the reader and writer together - you can't read and write from the same buffer
2. Run the reading and writing in seperate goroutines.  Because the first thing that gzip does is attempt to read the header you'll get a deadlock unless you have another go routine attemting to write it.

Here is what that looks like

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/H9hMjWu_uT)

```
func main() {
    s := []byte("Hello world!")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)

    in, out := io.Pipe()

    gz := gzip.NewWriter(out)
    go func() {
        ungz, err := gzip.NewReader(in)
        fmt.Println("err: ", err)
        uncomp := make([]byte, 100)
        n, err2 := ungz.Read(uncomp)
        fmt.Println("err2: ", err2)
        fmt.Println("n: ", n)
        uncomp = uncomp[:n]
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", uncomp)
    }()
    gz.Write(s)
    gz.Flush()    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that was exactly what I was looking for! I suppose that if I need to chain more filters, like compressing, encrypting and encoding, it should be done inside the go func(). I still thinking too sequentially for go. And I'm also assuming that Flush() will be propagated to the end, or it is too much to assume?

Comment: Chaining more filters should be fine, you just need to pump the start of the chain with a separate go routine to that you are taking stuff out the end to avoid deadlock.  Remember all IO in go is blocking, and if you don't want to block use a go routine. The `Flush` won't be propagated down the pipeline it is a gzip only thing.  However none of the above buffers stuff unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pipe. For example,

> [Package io](http://golang.org/pkg/io/)
>
> [func Pipe](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe)
>
> ```
> func Pipe() (*PipeReader, *PipeWriter)
> ```
>
> `Pipe` creates a synchronous in-memory pipe. It can be used to connect
>   code expecting an io.Reader with code expecting an io.Writer. Reads on
>   one end are matched with writes on the other, copying data directly
>   between the two; there is no internal buffering. It is safe to call
>   Read and Write in parallel with each other or with Close. Close will
>   complete once pending I/O is done. Parallel calls to Read, and
>   parallel calls to Write, are also safe: the individual calls will be
>   gated sequentially.